# Create a function to print an array

Tags: arrays, function, flowgorithm

I am having trouble creating a function to print arrays that works with any type. I have attempted the following function and main program:

[image: Here's the function]

[image: Here's the main program]

However, it does not work and I keep encountering new problems even after attempting to correct them. The error message is below:

[image: Here's the error message]

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Set the runspeed to slow (menu: `Program\run speed`), also show the variables (F9), and hit Run.   see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sy9X1.gif.   Happy debugging!

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason why you should check a value of -1 as an indicator of array end. There is a specific function: `Size()`. So your function could be:

[image: printE]

The XML version:

```xml
    <function name="printE" type="None" variable="">
        <parameters>
            <parameter name="tab" type="Integer" array="True"/>
        </parameters>
        <body>
            <declare name="i" type="Integer" array="False" size=""/>
            <for variable="i" start="0" end="Size(tab) - 1" direction="inc" step="1">
                <output expression="tab[i]" newline="True"/>
            </for>
        </body>
    </function>
```